# How to check health of kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know that i can use `kubectl get componentstatus` 
command to check the health status of the k8 cluster but  some how the output i am receiving do not show the health. Below is the output from master server.

[image]

I  can do deployments, can create pods and services which means everything is working fine but not sure how to check the health status.

Comment: `kubectl describe componentstatus` will provide you with a nice user friendly overview of the resources state. It should also display the audit of events, and where any failures or problems might be present.

Comment: I reconfigured my setup on centos... Still same result where as  ubuntu setup shows proper health status..

Comment: Has any one checked above command on centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** in kube-apiserver v1.17.0, also you should use command below in your older apiserver.

```
kubectl get cs -o=go-template='{{printf "NAME\t\t\tHEALTH_STATUS\tMESSAGE\t\n"}}{{range .items}}{{$name := .metadata.name}}{{range .conditions}}{{printf "%-24s%-16s%-20s\n" $name .status .message}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

enjoy

Answer (score 1):

can you try with this command

```
 kubectl get componentstatus -o jsonpath="{.items[*].conditions[*].status}"
```

I know both commands are same but outputting it as yaml worked for me

Comment: I don't think this is a helpful comment, why does showing the yaml help? It would be good to reference where they should look for useful information. Otherwise they'll be viewing a massive yaml with no idea where to look.

Comment: @DandyI have updated the answer which will only print health status

Comment: yeah above command shows result as true true true and now i think  'kubectl get componentstatus  command behaves differently on  centos and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
kubectl cluster-info
```